# This is about complex three number

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Thats one wrong with my code and I dont have any idea about this wrong
Please be attention to that I can just use from `for` and `while` and `if`

The question is:
Write a code that gets the natural number `n` then tries to  find `x,y,z` (natural numbers) in some way:
`n=x+y+z`

Then if the following is true of x, y, z, print these three numbers in the output, otherwise print the Not Found statement:

`x = y ^ 2 + z ^ 2`

(x or y or z) = `i + (i + 1) + (i + 2)`

Where i is a natural number.
Be it. Then if the following is true of x, y, z, print these three numbers in the output, otherwise print the Not Found statement:

`x = y ^ 2 + z ^ 2`

(x or y or z) = `i + (i + 1) + (i + 2)`

Where `i` is a natural number.

(Note that the input `n` is such that the `int` variable is sufficient and does not overflow.)

Input

The input contains a line in which a natural number is given.

Output

The output must either consist of three lines, each integer x, y, and z, respectively, from small to large, or the expression Not Found.

Example

Sample Input 1

48

Copy

Sample output 1

2 6 40

Copy

Sample input 2

5

Copy

Sample output 2

Not found

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() { 
    int z,x,y,n; 
    scanf("%u",&n); 
    for(y=1;y<(n/3);y++) {
        for(z=y;z<=((2*n)/3);z++) {
            (x=(n-(y+z))); 
            if(x==((y*y)+(z*z))) {
                if(((((y-3)%3)!=0)||(y==3))&&((((z-3)%3)!=0)||(z==3))&&((((x-3)%3)!=0)||(x==3))) {
                    continue; 
                } 
                printf("%d\n",y); 
                printf("%d\n",z); 
                printf("%d",x); return 0; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    printf("Not found"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your code is not easy to understand. You may want to add some comments and/or functions in the source code. What about this one, for example: `(((y-3)%3)!=0)||(y==3))` What's the intention? And you might want to reduce copy&paste.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax `(if(x==((yy)+(zz)))` is wrong. It should be `if (x == ((y*y)+(z*z)))` or use `pow function` from `math.h` library like this `(if(x == (pow(y,2)+pow(z,2)))`

```
int main()
{
    int z, x, y, n;
    scanf("%u", &n);
    for (y = 1; y < (n / 3); y++)
    {
        for (z = y; z <= ((2 * n) / 3); z++)
        {
            (x = (n - (y + z)));
            if (x == ((y*y)+(z*z)))
            {
                if (((((y - 3) % 3) != 0) || (y == 3)) && ((((z - 3) % 3) != 0) || (z == 3)) && ((((x - 3) % 3) != 0) || (x == 3)))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                printf("%d\n", y);
                printf("%d\n", z);
                printf("%d", x);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Not found");
    return 0; 
}
```